# Unexpected division/multiplication behaviour using C & Stellaris Launchpad

Tags: c

Weird happenings today. For some odd reason, I can't make division or multiplication of a value work, and even just reading out the value after writing it to a variable isn't working either. Here's the code fragment in question:

```
void Turning(heading,desiredheading){
//Boats heading too high

if (heading>desiredheading){
    if ((heading - desiredheading) <10 ){
        g_ulServoPulse[1]=makeAngle(5);
        g_ulServoPulse[2]=makeAngle(5);
    }else if((heading - desiredheading) <54 ){
        g_ulServoPulse[1]=makeAngle(27);
        g_ulServoPulse[2]=makeAngle(27);
    }else{
        g_ulServoPulse[1]=makeAngle((heading-desiredheading)*0.5);
        g_ulServoPulse[2]=makeAngle((heading-desiredheading)*0.5);

    }
//Boat is heading too low
}else if(desiredheading > heading){
    if ((desiredheading -heading) < 10 ){
        g_ulServoPulse[1]=makeAngle(-5);
        g_ulServoPulse[2]=makeAngle(-5);
    }else if ((desiredheading -heading) < 54 ){
        g_ulServoPulse[1]=makeAngle(-27);
        g_ulServoPulse[2]=makeAngle(-27);
    }else{
        g_ulServoPulse[1]=makeAngle((desiredheading-heading)*-0.5);
        g_ulServoPulse[2]=makeAngle((desiredheading-heading)*-0.5);}
        int temp = desiredheading-heading;
        //temp = temp ;
        UARTprintf("Wasp\n");
        UARTprintf("%d\n", desiredheading);
        UARTprintf("%d\n", heading);
        UARTprintf("%d\n", (desiredheading-heading));
        UARTprintf("%d\n", temp);

//Boat is Just right
}else{
    g_ulServoPulse[1]=makeAngle(0);
    g_ulServoPulse[2]=makeAngle(0);
    UARTprintf("Table\n");
}
}
```

So, it's just a straightforward comparator, with an operation happening for some range of values. Where 'temp' is in the code, has been temp*0.5 and temp*2.0, and either case, it's huge and wrong. In fact, even just writing out temp is wrong, as can be seen in the output below.

```
Wasp
180
177
3
1074266112

Wasp
180
150
30
1077805056
```

I can see no reason for the second last and last output to be different. And this is just for outputting temp, as mentioned the same issue exists for multiplication and division.

Any insight as to: Why this is is happening and how to fix it would be appreciated.

Cheers.

EDIT:
So apparently there is a strange roundabout method to make it behave.

```
int temp = desiredheading-heading;
temp &= 0xFF ;
```

Gets it to return correctly. Although I have absolutely no idea why this works, or what caused the original behavior.

Comment: what are the types for desiredheading and heading?

Comment: Does the output printed out correspond to (exactly) the code snippet in your posting?

Comment: The types should default to int.

Comment: If `desiredheading` and/or `heading` are pointers, and not `float`, `int`, etc, that would explain this behavior...

Comment: Hi guys, Cheers for the quick feedback. Desiredheading/Heading are int inputs, Yes the output corresponds exactly to the code snippet. I have found a roundabout solution though, I'll update the main post shortly

Comment: Hmm. ((int) 1074266112) & ((int) 0xFF) = 0. Which is not 3. There's something else here that must be fixed.

Comment: See the response posted by @chux. For the future, it helps us greatly if you make sure the output you post corresponds to the code snippet you post.

Comment: Apparently the solution is to force absolutely everything to be an integer. It fixes the stupid numbers.

Answer (score 3):

I really think there is a disconnect between the code shown and the results given.

```
UARTprintf("%d\n", temp); --> 1074266112
```

This just happens to be what you would get is you did this mis-match format and data type.
(Corrections applied due to @Daniel Fischer feedback)

```
UARTprintf("%d\n", 3.0);  --> 1074266112 = 0x40080000
UARTprintf("%d\n", 30.0); --> 1077805056 = 0x403E0000
```

Please double check the type of temp, heading, and desiredheading.
Also, is temp truly declared and computed via "int temp = desiredheading-heading;"?
It really looks like temp in "UARTprintf("%d\n", temp);" is a double.

Fair winds